# JavaScript: switch statement not setting hidden element value

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, getelementbyid

I have a simple `onChange()` function called from a `select` element, which should set a hidden element value, based on the `switch` value. I can get the switch statement working but the hidden element value doesn't get set - anything obvious here?

The function is called OK, as an alert statement at the end shows the correct value, eg, 'one@example/com' - I just cannot update the hidden element 'recipient' with the new value.

```
function setEmail() {
var s = document.getElementById('school_institute');
var school = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;
var x = document.getElementById('recipient');
switch(school) {
    case 'Name 1':
        x = 'one@example.com';
        break;
    case 'Name 2':
        x = 'two@example.com';
        break;
    default:
        x = 'three@example.com';
        break;
}
}
```

Would greatly appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[object HTMLInputElement].value` instead of overwriting the reference to the element:

```
function setEmail() {
    var s = document.getElementById('school_institute');
    var school = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;
    var x = document.getElementById('recipient');
    switch(school) {
        case 'Name 1':
            x.value = 'one@example.com';
            break;
        case 'Name 2':
            x.value = 'two@example.com';
            break;
        default:
            x.value = 'three@example.com';
            break;
    }
}
// x = document.getElementById('recipient');
// x = 'hello'; // Here we overwrite the reference to the node
// Instead set the value using `.value`
// x = document.getElementById('recipient');
// x.value = 'hello';
```